# Highest weight of a representation of a Lie Algebra

Tags: lie-algebras, weights

Given a Lie Algebra $\mathfrak{g}$, its Cartan Matrix $A$ and a finite representation $R$, is there a way of determining its highest weight $\Lambda$ in a simple way?

In my course, we consider $\mathfrak{g}=A_2= \mathfrak{L}_{\mathbb{C}}(SU(3))$. It is stated that the highest weight of the fundamental representation has Dynkin labels $\Lambda = (1,0)$ and the highest weight of the adjoint representation has Dynkin labels $\Lambda = (1,1)$. Why is it so? From there, I can work out the other roots by removing weights given by the Cartan Matrix but it is of no use if I can't compute the highest weight in the first place.

Taking an example, let $\mathfrak{g}=B_2= \mathfrak{L}_{\mathbb{C}}(SO(5))$. How do I work out the highest weight for the fundamental and adjoint representation?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, you let a maximal torus act and compute the weights ….

Comment: Thanks for answering! I am actually looking for a more direct approach, as the answers of the exercises I've been looking into just mention the values of the Dynkin labels with no further explanations. Maybe there are shortcuts for fundamental / adjoint representations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To obtain the highest weight of a semisimple Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ you first have to choose Cartan subalgebra $\mathfrak{h} \leq \mathfrak{g}$ and then set of positive roots (or alternatively choose a Borel subalgebra). Then the highest weight vectors of your representation $V$ are given by linear system 
$$
\rho(X) v = 0,\quad \forall X \in \bigoplus_{\alpha > 0} \mathfrak{g}_\alpha
$$
The set of such vectors $v \in V$ then gives you the number of irreducible constituents of your representation. The highest weight of each such subrepresentation is given by eigenvalues of $H_\alpha \in \mathfrak{h}$ for $\alpha$ simple.